# Restassured-Getting Specification to merge with cannot be null

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using the API as a reusable same API is used to get values for different dates.Only date is getting changed so i have used Request Specification but when i try to run getting the error message as Specification to merge with cannot be null[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucew7.jpg)

```
@BeforeEach
    public static void SetupRequestSpecBuilder() {
        reqBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
        reqBuilder.setContentType("application/json");
        reqBuilder.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        reqBuilder.addQueryParam("ap_type", apptype);
        reqBuilder.addQueryParam("days", days);
        reqBuilder.addQueryParam("room_id", roomid);
        reqBuilder.addQueryParam("date_req", today.toString());
        reqSpec = reqBuilder.build();

    }
    
     @Step("user perform a search for Current Day")
    public void GETDairySearch() {
        logger.info(("STEP: user perform a search"));
       response = SerenityRest.given().spec(reqSpec)
                .when()
                .get(endpoint + basePath);

        response.then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200);
        logger.info(" Endpoint is: :: " + endpoint + basePath);
        template_slot_id = response.jsonPath().getString("diary.template_slot_id[0]");
        template_slot_id_new = response.jsonPath().getString("diary.template_slot_id[1]");
        logger.info(" Slot_id_for_CurrentDay :: {}", template_slot_id);
        logger.info(("STEP: user perform a GET diary search"));
    }
    }
```

Comment: You can print out `reqSpec ` to check whether it is null or not.

Comment: Its printing Null

Comment: The code in `@BeforeEach` was never reached, you have to find another way to create `reqSpec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the  .spec(reqSpec) tried with .spec(SetupRequestSpecBuilder)
it worked